# Monitoring the outgoing requests

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, server

I'm trying to write small nuget package that catch all outgoing requests and to do some actions before they occur, for example to print the outgoing url to console.

I want to do that with the minimum intervention that required and without injecting nothing to controllers.

If you have a solution that work for all apps (not only asp or c#) that would be great.

Comment: You want to monitor the request made from the MVC application to the other web services/APIs?

Comment: Custom HttpClientFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests + custom HttpClientHandler maybe a good start ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya not only MVC, any app that send request to other APIs

Comment: @Tseng HttpClientFacotory it's a good solution for new apps, what if I want to monitoring existing app that not make use in HttpClient or monitoring outgoing request from SDK or others packages

Comment: If want a "one fits all" solution without code impact, then maybe you should be thinking about something like nmap instead?

Comment: @V.Amichai: W/o injecting a custom http client handler into the `HttpClient` class, I don't think its possible at all. The `HttpClientHandler` is the abstraction which does the actual http request. `HttpClient`is (simply said) a thin wrapper around the underlying `HttpRequestMessage`. It ends up, you either need to inject `HttpClient` (so you can configure the handlers in startup) or do it more abstract via Factory afaik

Comment: But actually the `HttpClient` should be logging this information already, if your log level is high enough. With the Logging MIddleware you can increase the loglevel of `"LogLevel": { "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Information" }` or higher in your appsettings.json (basically you tell the classes namespace or full-quallified name (namespace+class) and a log level after it. Everything using `ILogger<T>` will react to this

Comment: with just config and no coding, you can do see https://www.shanebart.com/dotnet-network-tracing/